# Using a returned vector

Tags: c++, if-statement, vector, compiler-errors, std

I have a class in my program that is used to read text from a file, store it as a vector of strings and then return that vector to the function that called it.

Then in that function I am trying to access the elements of a copy of the vector to compare the values.

It looks a bit like this:

filehandler.h

```
class fileHandler
{
public:
    std::vector<std::string> static ReadFromFile(std::string filename);

private:
    std::vector<std::string> blockOfText;
};
```

filehandler.cpp

```
std::vector<std::string> fileHandler::ReadFromFile(std::string filename)
{
//code to read file line by line and put into blockOfText

return blockOfText;
}
```

assetloader.cpp

```
void assetLoader::LoadFromExternalFile(std::string filename)
{
//Load the assets into the asset array
unsortedAssetText = ReadFromFile(filename);

//Iterate over the array
lineNumber = 0;
while (lineNumber < unsortedAssetText.size())
{
    if (unsortedAssetText[lineNumber] = "player")
    {

    }
}
```

Then when I try to build my program I get the following error, which I have no idea what it means let alone know how to fix the problem. Is anybody able to help?

```
error: could not convert '(&((assetLoader*)this)->assetLoader::unsortedAssetText.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >(((assetLoader*)this)->assetLoader::lineNumber))->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"player"))' from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'bool'|
```

Comment: I hope `blockOfText` is not a variable that goes out of scope at the end of `ReadFromFile`. That could cause you some real headaches.

Comment: I think I am having exactly that problem now @Daniel as my unsortedAssetText is always zero. I don't suppose there is a simple fix is there?

Comment: You could allocate it with the `new` keyword. But then be sure to `delete` it when it is no longer in use or you will have a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator, the comparison operator is `==`:

```
if (unsortedAssetText[lineNumber] == "player")
//                                ^^
```

Comment: Oh of course, I feel silly now. That's what no C++ and too much VBA does to you. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (unsortedAssetText[lineNumber] = "player")
```

to:

```
if (unsortedAssetText[lineNumber] == "player")
```

Comment: Oh of course, I feel silly now. That's what no C++ and too much VBA does to you. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to change the line

```
    if (unsortedAssetText[lineNumber] = "player")
```

to

```
    if (unsortedAssetText[lineNumber] == "player")
```